# Could not resolve host after removing KDE packages

Tags: linux, networking, debian, https, http

When the server was deployed, KDE was installed, it was not needed and I removed it.

Now when executing queries with any utilities (including apt) I get Could not resolve host.

What could I delete by mistake and how to make it work?

My server is Debian 9.2 (stretch)

Comment: what´ s in /etc/resolv.conf? As to what package, I think you need the dnsutils (https://packages.debian.org/stretch/dnsutils)

Comment: Great thanks! You saved my day! After I googled anout dns utils, I found that I also need bind_9 and now It's work!

Comment: On Linux the DNS is just managed with `/etc/resolv.conf` setting a DNS server like `8.8.8.8` there is enough to get name resolution to work. The DNS config file (`/etc/resolv.conf`) is the basis, every system/disto/config use an additional application to manage the DNS like: Resolvconf, Dnsmasq, NetworkManager (KDE), Rdnssd, Netconfig, Resolved, Bind, etc. All those DNS's applications does edit/update `/etc/resolv.conf` with the currently used DNS, on the other hand all network applications (client) does read the config file through `libc` to know what DNS to use to resolve internet's domains.

Answer (score -1):

Thanks to natxo asenjo, I was need in dnsutils and bind_9